# Extended ASCII in C#

Tags: c#, character-encoding, ascii, codepages

I want to store some of the extended ascii characters into a dictionary for lookup but having little issue with getting the conversion.

The current method I have to store these characters works for all the non-graphical looking ascii characters 0x20 to 0xAF.

Current method:

```
private static void LoadAnsiTable()
{
    for (byte i = 0x20; i < 0xFE; i++)
    {
      AnsiLookup.Add(i, Convert.ToChar(i).ToString());
    }
}
```

but the 0xAF and on does not have the ░ ▒ ▓ │ ┤╡ ╢ etc it just has these funky letters.

Looking at this table http://www.asciitable.com/ for reference.

This works if I manually add it,

```
AnsiLookup.Add(0xB0, "░");
```

I would like to know how I can get those symbols captured in some kind of collection without having to manually add them all?

Comment: "Extended ASCII" isn't any one single encoding. It's an annoyingly ambiguous term. Unfortunately asciitable.com doesn't actually say which encoding it's using.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume your "Extended ASCII" is actually [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437):

```
Encoding cp437 = Encoding.GetEncoding(437);
byte[] source = new byte[1];
for (byte i = 0x20; i < 0xFE; i++)
{
    source[0] = i;
    AnsiLookup.Add(i, cp437.GetString(source));
}
```

Beware that this code page is not natively supported by the .NET Framework, so it might not be available on all systems.

Comment: Is there actually any simple method of finding which encodings in .net are ascii-compatible?

Comment: @Nyerguds: Yes; see [Finding which encodings in .NET are ASCII-compatible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39052679/1149773)

Comment: @Douglas yea, found [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19695227/395685) instead. It solved my problem :)

Comment: Worked, Perfect.