# Finding which encodings in .NET are ASCII-compatible

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, ascii

Is there actually any simple method of finding which encodings in .NET are ASCII-compatible?

(Based on the question posed in [Nyerguds's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619279/extended-ascii-in-c-sharp#comment65426360_17619482).)

Comment: Downvoter: You do realize that [It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)? If there is anything wrong with the question and the answer, you should leave a comment so that readers would at least be aware of it.

Comment: It's the bane of SO. It really reduces the participation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will assume the standard definition of ASCII that is limited to 128 characters (namely, byte values whose most significant bit is 0). Unicode was designed such that its first 128 code points correspond to their ASCII equivalents. Since the numeric value of the `char` structure in .NET corresponds to its Unicode code point (except for surrogates), we can define a utility method like so:

```
private static readonly byte[] asciiValues = 
    Enumerable.Range(0, 128).Select(b => (byte)b).ToArray();

private static readonly string asciiChars = 
    new string(asciiValues.Select(b => (char)b).ToArray());

public static bool IsAsciiCompatible(Encoding encoding)
{
    try
    {
        return encoding.GetString(asciiValues).Equals(asciiChars, StringComparison.Ordinal)
            && encoding.GetBytes(asciiChars).SequenceEqual(asciiValues);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        // Encoding.GetString may throw DecoderFallbackException if a fallback occurred 
        // and DecoderFallback is set to DecoderExceptionFallback.
        // Encoding.GetBytes may throw EncoderFallbackException if a fallback occurred 
        // and EncoderFallback is set to EncoderExceptionFallback.
        // Both of these derive from ArgumentException.
        return false;
    }
}
```

We could then enumerate all .NET encodings like so:

```
var encodings = Encoding.GetEncodings().Select(e => e.GetEncoding()).ToList();
var asciiCompatible = encodings.Where(e => IsAsciiCompatible(e)).ToList();
var nonAsciiCompatbile = encodings.Except(asciiCompatible).ToList();

Console.WriteLine("ASCII compatible: ");
foreach (var encodingName in asciiCompatible.Select(e => e.EncodingName).OrderBy(n => n))
    Console.WriteLine("* " + encodingName);
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Non-ASCII compatible: ");
foreach (var encodingName in nonAsciiCompatbile.Select(e => e.EncodingName).OrderBy(n => n))
    Console.WriteLine("* " + encodingName);
```

Note that this method is not entirely safe. If there exists a multi-byte encoding that does fancy mappings of consecutive bytes or characters – such as decoding `0x61` to `'a'` and `0x62` to `'b'` (like in ASCII) but `0x6261` to `"�"` – then this test would give incorrect results.

Running this on .NET Fiddle ([snippet](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bRQlSZ)) gives the following results:

**ASCII compatible:**

- Arabic (864)
- Arabic (ASMO 708)
- Arabic (DOS)
- Arabic (ISO)
- Arabic (Mac)
- Arabic (Windows)
- Baltic (DOS)
- Baltic (ISO)
- Baltic (Windows)
- Central European (DOS)
- Central European (ISO)
- Central European (Mac)
- Central European (Windows)
- Chinese Simplified (EUC)
- Chinese Simplified (GB18030)
- Chinese Simplified (GB2312)
- Chinese Simplified (GB2312-80)
- Chinese Simplified (ISO-2022)
- Chinese Simplified (Mac)
- Chinese Traditional (Big5)
- Chinese Traditional (CNS)
- Chinese Traditional (Eten)
- Chinese Traditional (Mac)
- Croatian (Mac)
- Cyrillic (DOS)
- Cyrillic (ISO)
- Cyrillic (KOI8-R)
- Cyrillic (KOI8-U)
- Cyrillic (Mac)
- Cyrillic (Windows)
- Estonian (ISO)
- French Canadian (DOS)
- Greek (DOS)
- Greek (ISO)
- Greek (Mac)
- Greek (Windows)
- Greek, Modern (DOS)
- Hebrew (DOS)
- Hebrew (ISO-Logical)
- Hebrew (ISO-Visual)
- Hebrew (Mac)
- Hebrew (Windows)
- IBM5550 Taiwan
- Icelandic (DOS)
- Icelandic (Mac)
- ISCII Assamese
- ISCII Bengali
- ISCII Devanagari
- ISCII Gujarati
- ISCII Kannada
- ISCII Malayalam
- ISCII Oriya
- ISCII Punjabi
- ISCII Tamil
- ISCII Telugu
- Japanese (EUC)
- Japanese (JIS 0208-1990 and 0212-1990)
- Japanese (Mac)
- Japanese (Shift-JIS)
- Korean
- Korean (EUC)
- Korean (Johab)
- Korean (Mac)
- Korean Wansung
- Latin 3 (ISO)
- Latin 9 (ISO)
- Nordic (DOS)
- OEM Cyrillic
- OEM Multilingual Latin I
- OEM United States
- Portuguese (DOS)
- Romanian (Mac)
- TCA Taiwan
- TeleText Taiwan
- Thai (Windows)
- Turkish (DOS)
- Turkish (ISO)
- Turkish (Mac)
- Turkish (Windows)
- Ukrainian (Mac)
- Unicode (UTF-8)
- US-ASCII
- Vietnamese (Windows)
- Wang Taiwan
- Western European (DOS)
- Western European (ISO)
- Western European (Mac)
- Western European (Windows)

**Non-ASCII compatible:**

- Chinese Simplified (HZ)
- Europa
- German (IA5)
- IBM EBCDIC (Arabic)
- IBM EBCDIC (Cyrillic Russian)
- IBM EBCDIC (Cyrillic Serbian-Bulgarian)
- IBM EBCDIC (Denmark-Norway)
- IBM EBCDIC (Denmark-Norway-Euro)
- IBM EBCDIC (Finland-Sweden)
- IBM EBCDIC (Finland-Sweden-Euro)
- IBM EBCDIC (France)
- IBM EBCDIC (France-Euro)
- IBM EBCDIC (Germany)
- IBM EBCDIC (Germany-Euro)
- IBM EBCDIC (Greek Modern)
- IBM EBCDIC (Greek)
- IBM EBCDIC (Hebrew)
- IBM EBCDIC (Icelandic)
- IBM EBCDIC (Icelandic-Euro)
- IBM EBCDIC (International)
- IBM EBCDIC (International-Euro)
- IBM EBCDIC (Italy)
- IBM EBCDIC (Italy-Euro)
- IBM EBCDIC (Japanese katakana)
- IBM EBCDIC (Korean Extended)
- IBM EBCDIC (Multilingual Latin-2)
- IBM EBCDIC (Spain)
- IBM EBCDIC (Spain-Euro)
- IBM EBCDIC (Thai)
- IBM EBCDIC (Turkish Latin-5)
- IBM EBCDIC (Turkish)
- IBM EBCDIC (UK)
- IBM EBCDIC (UK-Euro)
- IBM EBCDIC (US-Canada)
- IBM EBCDIC (US-Canada-Euro)
- IBM Latin-1
- IBM Latin-1
- ISO-6937
- Japanese (JIS)
- Japanese (JIS-Allow 1 byte Kana - SO/SI)
- Japanese (JIS-Allow 1 byte Kana)
- Korean (ISO)
- Norwegian (IA5)
- Swedish (IA5)
- T.61
- Thai (Mac)
- Unicode *(UTF-16)*
- Unicode (Big-Endian)
- Unicode (UTF-32 Big-Endian)
- Unicode (UTF-32)
- Unicode (UTF-7)
- Western European (IA5)

Comment: Very nice solution. One thing, though: Encoding.GetString [can throw an exception on invalid decoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc(v=vs.110).aspx) if the encoding object is initialized with options to do so (see the constructors for `UTF8Encoding` and `UTF16Encoding`), so it's always safer to surround it with a try-catch that simply returns False. The exception to catch for that is an `ArgumentException`.

Comment: @Nyerguds: Good point. I've updated the code per your suggestion.

Comment: By the way, the reason I needed this was to use in combination with [this method I wrote](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33681871/395685) that auto-detects encoding. If you start with a user-configured encoding (like Win-1252) and auto-detect on text whether it is UTF-8 or not, you can't blindly take the output encoding if you still need it for other purposes, since it reduces it to bare ASCII if the text only contains ASCII text. So with this added I can determine if the detection itself should even be done, and if so, I can be sure that returned ascii should be ignored.