# Convert extended ASCII character codes to ISO-8859-1

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding

I am in the process of porting data from a legacy system, but I am unsure what encoding it uses internally to store the data. I have noticed that the data corresponds to ASCII code values (i.e. character ë, or small letter e with diaeresis, is stored as byte value 137 as per [this](http://www.asciitable.com/) chart).

I need to encode the data using ISO-8859-1 for the destination system, but obviously using the data as-is yields the incorrect results (in ISO-8859-1 the per mille sign is represented by decimal 137, as per [this](http://www.ascii-code.com/) chart).

I need some advice on what encoding I can use when reading the data - i.e. an encoding that corresponds to the decimal ASCII code values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619279/extended-ascii-in-c-sharp) SO post. It turns out that code page 437 corresponds to the extended ASCII character codes. I was thus able to re-encode the data as follows:

```
var output = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.GetEncoding(437), Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"), input);
```